# Vectorize left join on time with pandas/numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, join, vectorization

I have two dataframes: `x` and `y`.  My objective is to left join y on x where `x.timestamp` is between y min and max (and to count these occurrences).

```
x.shape
(69593, 1)

x.head()
timestamp   count
4   2013-06-01 04:12:34 0
5   2013-06-01 04:19:08 0
6   2013-06-01 05:18:35 0
7   2013-06-01 06:00:19 0
8   2013-06-01 09:16:13 0

y.head()
min max
0   2013-06-02 09:10:51 2013-06-02 10:27:44
1   2013-06-12 03:08:35 2013-06-12 03:08:35
2   2013-08-03 09:11:35 2021-01-26 23:05:17

y.shape
(3, 2)
```

Using the lambda function on each row works in this case, but it is incredibly slow (between 45s and 60s to join a table of 3 rows to a table of  ~70k rows).

```
%%time
x['count'] = \
    x.apply(lambda r: len(y.loc[(y['min']<=r['timestamp']) & (y['max']>=r['timestamp'])]), axis=1)
```

Is there a method in `numpy` that would vectorize this join or are there other suggestions to make this join run faster(under 5s) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For general solution also with overlapping use cross join first, then filter rows by conditions and last add new column with [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) an count matched values by [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
df = x.assign(a=1).merge(y.assign(a=1), on='a')
s = df.loc[(df['min']<=df['timestamp']) & (df['max']>=df['timestamp']), 'timestamp']

x['count'] = x['timestamp'].map(s.value_counts()).fillna(0).astype(int)
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no overlap between timestamps in `x` and min/max in `y`. I had to change the first record in `y` dataframe:

```
>>> y
Out[124]: 
                  min                 max
0 2013-05-10 09:10:51 2013-06-02 10:27:44
1 2013-06-12 03:08:35 2013-06-12 03:08:35
2 2013-08-03 09:11:35 2021-01-26 23:05:17
```

But when you do have overlap you can do the merge with `merge_asof()`:

```
foo = pd.merge_asof(x, y, left_on='timestamp', right_on='min', direction='backward')
valid_idx = np.where(foo.timestamp >= foo['max'])[0]
new_cols = foo.loc[valid_idx, :]
foo = pd.merge(x, new_cols, left_index=True, right_index=True, suffixes=('_1', '_2'))
```